# SharePoint 2010 custom breadcrumb, change only HTML

Tags: sharepoint, css-float, breadcrumbs

I have a requirement for changing the way bread crumbs looks in sharepoint. Please note that the data source will still be sharepoint but i need to generate the html little differently than the one displayed by sharepoint.

for example, if you are in a custom list,sharepoint displays as site > custom list > all items.

I neeed to display site, custom list and all items (no change in the items that are got from sharepoint). The only change will be, the user interface will be generated with a combination of html ul tags with some custom css?

Can someone suggest me the best approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The visual appearance of the `SiteMapPath` control that displays a breadcrumb can be modified by setting the attributes of the control or by configuring the templates that are available for the control. I think that the `CssClass` and `NodeTemplate` properties is what you need.

- [How to: Customize the Appearance of SiteMapPath Web Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178419.aspx)
- [SiteMapPath Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemappath_properties.aspx)
- [Using a template with the SiteMapPath control](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0180__Development/UsingatemplatewiththeSiteMapPathcontrol.htm)

---

To modify the content of the breadcrumb you need to create a custom site map provider inheriting from `SPContentMapProvider`.

- [SharePoint Branding Issues: Breadcrumb](http://tomblog.insomniacminds.com/2007/10/25/sharepoint-branding-issues-breadcrumb/)
- [How to Create custom XMLSiteMapProvider and render it in SharePoint 2007 MOSS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedi/archive/2008/09/03/how-to-create-custom-xmlsitemapprovider-and-render-it-in-sharepoint-2007-moss.aspx)

Comment: useful to an extent. But im only looking to change the user interface...to be more clear...i would like the same hierarchy data that is got from providers to be displayed on the screen but in a different manner..this means i will not be generating the site map data...will just be using what sharepoint provides but need to override the way html is generated..let me know for any clarifications

Comment: Thanks, im aware..im having breadcrumbs already as part of a custom web part..the rendering logic is written in the render method of web part. i quickly want to move this rendering logic to a breadcrumb..tried inheriting from PortalSiteMapProvider but it does not have a render method that can be overriden..any inputs?

Comment: @Faiz: Did you try to change the `CssClass` and `NodeTemplate` values? Or don't you know how to change the default breadcrumb?